# IllegalStateException for MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

I have a game in which one can toggle sound on and off by a button. However, if sound is on, after onPause() and returning to onResume() to running, if the player tries to make an action, the game crashes. In contrast, on soundless mode, gameplay continues seamlessly.

This is the diagnosis generated by logcat:

Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1143)
        at nocompany.rect.MainActivity.playSound(MainActivity.java:85)
        at nocompany.rect.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:165)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

These are the relevant codes in my project:

MainActivity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sound=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.chaching);
}
public void playSound()
{
    if (!noSound)
    sound.start();
}
private boolean noSound=false;
public void noSound(View v){
    if (!noSound) {
        {
            noSound = !noSound;
            soundBut.setImageResource(R.drawable.nosound);
        }
    } else {
        noSound = !noSound;
        soundBut.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound);=

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any `onPause()` or `onResume()` code that could be included in your question?

Comment: Yeah that was the issue. I forgot to recreate MediaPlayer onResume(). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it! _(And you may want to consider adding an answer to this question at some point in the future...)_

Comment: the code used can´t compile you have a method plySound() inside onCreate()....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not explicitly displayed but arises due to what is NOT in onResume(). By having the MediaPlayer created in onCreate(), after returning from onPause(), the activity does not go through onCreate() and thus there is no MediaPlayer. To resolve this issue, one would put the setup for MediaPlayer in onResume().

This is the following code used to resolve the issue:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sound=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.chaching);
}
```